# Shuffle columns in pairs

Tags: pandas, random, shuffle

I have the following dataframe:

```
d = {'Name1':['jaap','piet','tim'],'Name2':['bas','max','piet'], 'Count1':[1,5,2],'Count2' :[2,6,8], 'Win','[1,2,2]}

data = pd.DataFrame(d)

  Name1 Name2  Count1  Count2   Win
0  jaap   bas       1       2     1
1  piet   max       5       6     2
2   tim  piet       2       8     2
```

Now I want to randomly shuffle the columns in pairs, row by row. So `Count1` belongs to `Name1` and `Count2` belongs to `Name2`. So in case the name in the column `Name1` is shuffled with the name in `Name2`, then also the value in column `Count1` is shuffled with the value in column `Count2`. But also the values in the last column `Win` must be changed from 2 to 1 and vice versa whenever a shuffle is applied in a specific row.

Example output would be:

```
  Name1 Name2  Count1  Count2  Win
0  bas   jaap       2       1   2
1  piet  max        5       6   2
2  piet  tim        8       2   1
```

Hereby row `0` and `2` are shuffled.

Proceedings:

```
np.apply_along_axis(np.random.permutation, 1, data[['Name1','Name2']])

np.apply_along_axis(np.random.permutation, 1, data[['Count1','Count2']])
```

This however doesn't ensure the same shuffle is applied for Name1 and Name2 as for Count1 and Count2.

And:

```
data['random'] = np.random.choice(2,len(data))
data['random1'] = data['random'].replace([1,0],[0,1])

name1 = data['Name1'].copy()
name2 = data['Name2'].copy()
count1 = dft['Count1'].copy()
count2 = data['Count2'].copy()
data['Name1'] = name1 * data['random'] + name2 *data['random1']
data['Name2'] = name1 * data['random1'] + name2 * data['random']
data['Count1'] = odds1 * data['random'] + count2 *data['random1']
data['Count2'] = odds1 * data['random1'] + count2 * data['random']
```

The second approach works for column pairs `Name` and `Count` but not for the last `win` column. I am looking for a better method that is easily applied to multiple column pairs.

Answer (score 1):

We can generate the `random` sample followed `argsort` to obtain the randomly shuffled indices which can be used to shuffle the given columns along `axis=1`, In order to change the `Win` column we can create a mask to check for the order of shuffled indices if the order is changed then substitute the values in `Win` by reverse mapping

```
c1 = ['Name1', 'Name2']
c2 = ['Count1', 'Count2']

i = np.random.rand(len(data), 2).argsort(1)

data[c1] = np.take_along_axis(data[c1].values, i, axis=1)
data[c2] = np.take_along_axis(data[c2].values, i, axis=1)

data['Win'] = data['Win'].where((i == [0, 1]).all(1), data['Win'].map({1:2, 2:1}))
```

---

```
  Name1 Name2  Count1  Count2  Win
0   bas  jaap       2       1    2
1  piet   max       5       6    2
2  piet   tim       8       2    1
```